# How to loop json data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON data is like

```
{
    "Brand":["EM-03","TORRES"],
    "Price":["5.00000","10.00000","15.00000"],
    "Country":["US","SG"]
}
```

I want to loop that JSON data to get

```
Brand = 
  EM-03 -
  TORRES

Price = 
  5.00000 -
  10.00000 -
  15.00000

Country = US - SG
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Or should I say: have you tried *anything*?

Answer (score 1):

With [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
   console.log(value); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
   console.log(value.join('-')); 
});
```